# Is there a way we can re-use value of defined keys in EDN?

Tags: clojure, edn

Is there a way I can reuse values of key defined in EDN?

For ex:
If I have following EDN

```
{
   :abc "value1"
   :def :abc
}
```

When I read above EDN in Clojure, I want for 'def' key, value1 which is value of :abc to be passed. But currently :abc string is getting is passed when I read it using EDN read-string function

Comment: No, you’ll have to implement it yourself. [Fern](https://github.com/cognitect-labs/fern) is an edn format that supports something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing in plain EDN. But you could build a two phase pass, either by replacing things first on the EDN string itself, or possibly better to do it after the EDN was parsed by manipulating a data-strucure for example:

```
(require '[clojure.edn :as edn])
(require '[clojure.walk :as walk])

(defrecord self [key])
(defn tag-self
  [v]
  (->self v))

(defn custom-readers []
  {'x/self tag-self})

(defn replace-self
  [coll]
  (walk/prewalk
   (fn [form]
     (if (map? form)
       (reduce-kv
        (fn [acc k v]
          (assoc acc k (if (= self (type v))
                         (get form (:key v))
                         v)))
        {}
        form)
       form))
   coll))

(replace-self
 (edn/read-string
  {:readers (custom-readers)}
  "[{:abc \"value1\"
     :def #x/self :abc}
    {:abc {:bbb \"value2\"
           :def #x/self :bbb}
     :def #x/self :abc
     :xyz {:aaa \"value3\"
           :nope #x/self :abc
           :def #x/self :aaa}}]"))
```

Will return:

```
[{:abc "value1", :def "value1"}
 {:abc {:bbb "value2", :def "value2"},
  :def {:bbb "value2", :def "value2"},
  :xyz {:aaa "value3", :nope nil, :def "value3"}}]
```

The trick is that I mark the references to another key of the current map using the `#x/self` tag reader that I created, which will wrap the value in a `self` record. Now we just walk over the returned data-structure, and every time we encounter a `self` type, we replace it by the value of its `:key` attribute in the same map.

The above `replace-self` walker is recursive, so you can see that it can handle nested maps and it can even replace `self` references inside map that are themselves `self` referenced. It does local scoping only though, so `:nope #x/self :abc` did not get replaced by the value of the `:abc` in the parent map, and since there was no `:abc` key in its own map, its value was set to `nil`.

The custom tag is optional, I did it this way cause now it works for any type of key. But you could use `keyword?` instead in replace-self as well if you want this to be the behavior for them:

```
(defn replace-self
  [coll]
  (walk/prewalk
   (fn [form]
     (if (map? form)
       (reduce-kv
        (fn [acc k v]
          (assoc acc k (if (keyword? v)
                         (v form)
                         v)))
        {}
        form)
       form))
   coll))

(replace-self
 (edn/read-string
  "[{:abc \"value1\"
     :def :abc}
    {:abc {:bbb \"value2\"
           :def :bbb}
     :def :abc
     :xyz {:aaa \"value3\"
           :nope :abc
           :def :aaa}}]"))
```

This will return the same as before, just no need for a custom tag and the self record:

```
[{:abc "value1", :def "value1"}
 {:abc {:bbb "value2", :def "value2"},
  :def {:bbb "value2", :def "value2"},
  :xyz {:aaa "value3", :nope nil, :def "value3"}}]
```

Comment: Doing this in the EDN string itself seems like a tremendous amount of work for a very fragile result. I wouldn't even mention it in the answer, when you already provide a much higher quality solution.